# KIA0104 - This host has no matching entry in the service registry

Tags: istio, istio-gateway, kiali, istio-kiali

First thing: everything seems to works correctly and security policy does his job (according to unit-test)... but Kiala things I have some problems.

All my services (ServiceAccount/Service/Deployment) are on namespace 'app'.

My gateway is deployed on namespace 'app'.

My policy ares installed on namespace 'istio-system' to deal with JWT correctly...

Kiali error is on > hosts: ["authenticator.app.io"]

*This rule rejects all requests with a token to "login".*

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: gateway-deny-token-login
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  action: DENY
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals: ["auth@app.io/*"]
    to:
    - operation:
        hosts: ["authenticator.app.io"]
        paths: ["/auth/login"]
```

According to: https://kiali.io/docs/features/validations/
The present validation points out those rules referencing a host that don’t exist in the authorization policy namespace. Kiali considers services and service entries. **Those hosts that refers to hosts outside of the object namespace will be presented with an unknow error."**

But "ingressgateway" & JWT rules ares on namespace "istio-system" and my services are on my namespace.

How made Kiali happy ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution...
I don't know if it's "the" solution, but it works.

1 - I have configured 'ingress' with the host: ["*"] for HTTP and HTTPS redirection (Gateway).

2 - I did not touch the configuration of "jwtRules" (RequestAuthentication).

3 - I grouped all my "VirtualService" into one and exposing the api of my different "hosts" with "HTTPRoute".

4 - I have rewritten the "AuthorizationPolicy" to match the new api mapping.

*Note: Don't forget to delete the old "VirtualService".*

After that everything works as before, but I no longer need to specify "host" in the header of the request, but above all, I am no longer Kiali errors!